# What is the opposite of a robust system?

Tags: terminology

Matrix inversion is not robust in the sense that a small difference in the input  can give a large difference in the output. Is there an appropriate word to describe such a system?

Comment: Condition number.

Comment: By analogy to "robust", "fragile" sounds good

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I know of that related concept, but it is quite specific and also isn't even an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

Related to DumpsterDoofus's comment, I've always seen the adjective "ill-conditioned", which happens to be used on [the wikipedia page for condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number)

Answer (score 0):

- Sensitivity, or
- sensitive dependence on the input.

Moreover, if your "system" consists of a repeated operation, e.g. 
$$x_n\to x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$
the *sensitive dependence of $x_n$ on the initial condition $x_0$* is denoted [Chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Sensitivity_to_initial_conditions).